# 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. PHP SOUND

Tags: php, error-handling

I am using Xampp - vm for Mac osx.

I am having trouble with my `phpsound` installation. I keep receiving 403 error, which I have googled and read all the overflow comments.

I'm fairly new to this and have changed the permission of my folder for ex, file/get info/ change to read only. This did not work.

I also went into `httpd-xampp.conf` and edited to require all granted. Yet I am still getting the same error.

Is there anyway around this?

P.S - apology for the lack of info or coding language used

thanks